# Pass member name as argument

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

Is possible pass only the name of method / function (member) without parameters?
Something similar to what Moq does:

```
    Mock<Foo>fooMoq = new Mock<Foo>();
    fooMoq.Setup(f => f.DummyMethod(It.IsAny<string>()));
```

but, without It.IsAny  ():

```
    Mock<Foo> fooMoq = new Mock<Foo>();
    fooMoq.Setup(f => f.DummyMethod);
```

I don't mean in the context of Moq, but in general.
Thanks.

Edit:
I want to obtain is the name of the member, to later intercept calls to that method. That's why I'm not interested in knowing what parameters will be passed to the method, I just want to know what methods they want to intercept.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? How do you want to use passed method? Do you want to extract some information, call it or what?

Comment: You would still need to call the desired member as defined. Just pass default values for the parameters ie `fooMoq.Setup(_ => _.DummyMethod(null));`. The `Setup` method can then extract the method name from the expression.

Comment: This feels like 
an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to achieve. In what context?

Comment: In the case of overloads you should actually take the MethodInfo as apposed to just the member name alone

Comment: Is this for methods only or does it include properties?

Comment: In principle only for methods. Although it's more curious than anything else :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't pass method from an instance of lambda parameter. The closest you can get is to use method group conversion. However you didn't really specify what you want to achieve.

After OP edit:

There is no easier way to do it, that's why popular frameworks like MOQ requires from you to pass all required parameters. One of common ways of doing this is just pass a method with only nulls (or default values for value types) like this:

```
fooMoq.Setup(f => f.DummyMethod(null,null,null));
```

There is also one more approach which allow you to not pass any parameters but you lose static type check for the type of a method so you can pass any method name there. Also reading it will be more problematic because you'll only have method name and type which can cause issues when reading overloaded functions.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
       Setup<Test>(nameof(Test.DummyMethod));
    }

    public static void Setup<T>(string methodName)
    {

    }
}

public class Test
{
    public void DummyMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, the problem of nameof is losing the static type check. It is also true that I had not thought about overloaded functions ... In any case, what I have most of all is curiosity. I believe that it is not possible to achieve it (that's why I ask :)).

Comment: @luisNET if it answers your question then mark it as an answer.